# Corda - Passing Anonymous Implementations Over RPC

Tags: corda

Is it possible to pass anonymous object implementations over Corda's RPC interface? - For example:

### Workflow

```kotlin
@CordaSerializable
interface ExampleInterface {
    val number: Int
}

@StartableByRPC
class SquareFlow(private val example: ExampleInterface) : FlowLogic<Int>() {
    
    @Suspendable
    override fun call(): Int = example.number * example.number
}
```

### RPC Client

```kotlin
val value = object : ExampleInterface {
    override val number: Int = 5
}

return rpc.startFlowDynamic(SquareFlow::class.java, value).returnValue.getOrThrow()
```

### Exception

> net.corda.client.rpc.RPCException: java.util.List<*> -> Unable to create an object serializer for type class com.example.client.ExampleService$square$value$1: No unique deserialization constructor can be identified
>
> Either annotate a constructor for this type with @ConstructorForDeserialization, or provide a custom serializer for it

Whilst this is an example, what I actually want to do is pass `object : TypeReference<SomeType>(){}` over RPC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per Corda's docs anonymous objects are not supported by their AMQP
serialization which is used in the RPC client which you can read [here](https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-enterprise/4.6/serialization.html#kotlin-objects). This is likely due to a public constructor being needed for serialization and deserialization I imagine.

Additionally I assume you are referencing Jackson's `TypeReference` class which uses generics which are only available at compile time. Due to how Corda's serialization works the generic won't be available at runtime so when the TypeReference is passed from the rpc application to the corda node the corda node will not know what the generic is. I haven't tried this myself but I believe some exception will be thrown whenever the flow attempts to suspend or possibly before in the RPC client.

You can probably pass a jackson `JavaType` class to a flow without a problem as I believe it is whitelisted as serializable in Corda by default, if not look at how to whitelist the class [here](https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-enterprise/4.6/serialization.html#whitelisting) using the `SerializationWhitelist`. You can obtain the `JavaType` by instantiating a `TypeFactory` and calling `constructType(new TypeReference<SomeType> {})`. then just pass the JavaType to your flows constructor.